# Set back UIScreen Brightness to user setting

Tags: iphone, ios5, brightness, settings, uiscreen

in some of the views of my iPhone app I set the screen brightness pragmatically like:

```
  [[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness:1.0];
```

then on

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
 {
 }
```

I will like to set it  back to its original value. To do this how do I get the current UIScreen brightness value before I set it to 1.

tanx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"brightness" is a property, so it has a corresponding accessor.  So just use:

```
CGFloat oldBrightness = [[UIScreen mainScreen] brightness];
```